# Monax installation error

Tags: node.js, docker, blockchain

I am trying to install  monax on Ubuntu from this link:   https://monax.io/docs/getting-started/

When I execute **monax init** I am getting error that says monax:command not found.
I have installed docker and downloaded monax.

Comment: Have you set `$GOBIN` variable value in your `$PATH` as suggested in the [docs](https://monax.io/docs/install-troubleshooting/#no-monax-command-found) of monax?

Comment: Yes.But when I executed cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/monax/monax/cmd/monax  . Output : no such file or directory